# Why does my "If" block fail to act as a typeguard in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm attempting to write an application with Angular 4.4.6 and Typescript 2.4.2. with the "strictNullChecks" compiler option set to true.

At the top of my component class, I am declaring a property for a form like so:

```
BasicForm: FormGroup | null;
```

Then I initialize my form in the `OnInit` lifecycle hook. Like so:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.BasicForm = new FormGroup({
   name : new FormControl('')
  });
}
```

**Problem**

When I try to reference my form in a class method, the compiler yells at me, saying "Object is possibly null"...Which confuses me, because I have the reference wrapped in an if block that checks for null.

```
myMethod(){
    if(this.BasicForm){
      let name = this.BasicForm.get('name').value;
    }
}
```

To solve this problem, I have to add an non-null assertion operator before accessing my value property.Like so:

```
myMethod(){
    if(this.BasicForm){
      let name = this.CampgroundForm.get('name')!.value;
    }
}
```

But I don't like using this...It seems to be counter productive to what TS is trying to achieve.

**Why doesn't control flow analysis work here with my typeguard? Is there a better way than adding the non-null assertion operator?**

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `null` warning is actually on the result of `BasicForm.get()`.

It might get a little bit ugly to work around:

```
myMethod(){
    if(this.BasicForm){
        let prop = this.BasicForm.get('name');
        if (prop){
            let name = prop.value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could try adding a helper method that wraps the null check logic:

```
myMethod(){
    let name = this._formGet('name');
    if(name){
        // do stuff with name
    }
}

_formGet(prop){
    let result;
    if(this.BasicForm){
        let prop = this.BasicForm.get('name');
        if (prop){
            result = prop.value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you're going to be doing that sort of thing a lot, then it might be useful to look into learning about some data types that help you avoid null checks: https://github.com/cbowdon/TsMonad#general-maybe-usage

Comment: I ended up writing my own helper method for my own specific use case. Thank you for you guidance and help...it certainly helped. On a side note, this problem looks to be fixed soon. https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20040

Comment: Glad it helped. You'll still have to keep your helper after that pull request lands, it just adds generics support - the result of `AbstractControl.get()` will still be nullable.